# How to get UIImageView Size (any Object Like UIButton, UILabel) in UITableViewCell. I used Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have UIView, UILabel, and UIImageView in UITableViewCell.

I want to **get Width of UIImageView in (tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath)** when cell is loading because I want to set the height of UIImageView According to width of UIImageView.

**I used UITableViewAutomaticDimension**

Actually I want to get width of UIImageView according to iPhone 8 its original size in iPhone 5

I make cell for **iPhone 8  and UIImageView size 390 * 390**
In **iPhone 5 I get same and UIImageView size 390 *** 390. **I did not get size according to iPhone5**

Please help me.[image: UIView AutoLayout]

[image: UILabel Autolayout]

[image: UIImageView Autolayout]

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need to get the width of an image to have its height constrained to its width. What you're probably looking for is 1:1 Aspect Ratio constraint like this for your image:
[image]

Here's how it would look like on a real image:
[image]

Results would look like this:
**iPhone 5**
[image]

**iPhone 8** 
[image]

Comment: please do not assume that i need sqaure UIImageView
I want to make rectangle UIImageView. I have some calculation that depend on width of UIImageView

Comment: I have UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Comment: It's easy to adjust the image to be rectangular using the aspect ratio. You can set it to 1:0.5 for instance. You can also use specific dimensions, for instance image needs to be 200x100 on iPhone 8 and proportionally scaled on iPhone 5, you can set the aspect ratio to 200:100.

Comment: thanks for information 
I have UItableViewCell 1024 * 500 in ipad 
if I have my other objects which are very next to UIImageView Rect 200*100 and I use ration 2:1 according to Previous Comment and what happened with others objects which is next to UIIMageView Rect 

For Ex UIImageVIew Frame (10,10)(200,100) and
next UIButton Frame (220,10)(300,300) (with 10 pixel padding with UIImageVIew)

Comment: are all objects which are very next to UIImageView are set according to Constraints

Comment: They're all resized according to constraints, yes. If you've set up button margin constraints relative to your `UIImageView`, when image view updates, the button will be moved accordingly. I highly recommend reading at least the basics of autolayout as it's instrumental in understanding how to construct interfaces in iOS applications https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

Comment: Thanks I got it i jut confirm myself asking about my last comment Question

Thank from bottom of my heart For your co operation